# R Average of column when value of other column is equal

Tags: r, average

I have table "age" like this:

```
Age State
23    1
26    3
29    1
41    2
51    1
```

For such a problem the easiest way to take average of Age for those ones who have State = 1

Answer (score 7):

If we just need the `mean` of 'Age' where 'State' is 1, subset the 'Age' values that corresponds to 'State' of 1 and get the `mean`

```
mean(df1$Age[df1$State==1])
```

Or if we need `mean` of 'Age' per each 'State' group, one option is `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Age~State, df1, FUN=mean)
```

Or we use `data.table` where we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), get the 'mean` of 'Age', grouped by 'State'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Age=mean(Age)), State]
```

Answer (score 4):

and so:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(ave = mean(Age)) %>% filter(State == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do...
`mean(subset(df1,State == 1)$Age)`